# Register Twig Extension in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I want to use [nochso/html-compress-twig extension](https://github.com/nochso/html-compress-twig#usage) to compress all html, inline css and js.But it is the first time that I register a new extension on Twig and I am bit confused about where I should add the following lines in my project:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new \nochso\HtmlCompressTwig\Extension());
```

I was reading the Twig's documentation but it didn't helped me much as they put the same example and just add the following:

```
Twig does not care where you save your extension on the filesystem, as all extensions must be registered explicitly to be available in your templates.

You can register an extension by using the addExtension() method on your main Environment object:
```

I only want enable the extension globally and be able to use `{% htmlcompress %}{% endhtmlcompress %}` in any twig template

Comment: You better follow the Symfony specific documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: do not forget to choose the right symfony version that you are using too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can register your twig extension as a tagged service this way:

```
services:
    htmlcompress:
        class: '\nochso\HtmlCompressTwig\Extension'
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It worked without any problem, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To enable a Twig extension, add it as a regular service... http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#twig-extension

Comment: Thaks for your reply! In this case after install the bundle how should I enable it in services.yml? I tried this: `    app.compress:
        class: \nochso\HtmlCompressTwig\Extension
        tags: [twig.extension]` But I guess that I should change "twig.extension" for another name...

Comment: no, you should not change 'twig.extension' for another name. That's not a name. That is a flag that tells symfony that your service is a Twig  extension.  Have you try to pass 'true' as an argument as per the documention ?  Compression is disabled by Twig's debug setting. This is to make development easier, however you can always override it.

The constructor of this extension takes a boolean parameter $forceCompression. When true, this will force compression regardless of Twig's debug setting. It defaults to false when omitted.

Comment: I tried both options, leaving "twig.extension" raises an exception telling me `A "tags" entry must be an array for service "app.compress"`. I also tried to pass true as an argument but I need to configure it in the right way first

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources